# How to add spaces to triangles

Tags: java

So I've been at this for a while and I have am not sure how to do this so my professor wants us to print out triangles using for statements I accomplished this. But I have to add spaces to different columns in two of these triangles and I'm confused of how to do this. Here is what I have so far:

```
// Lab 11: Triangles.java
// Program prints four triangles, one below the other
public class Triangles
{
   // draw four triangles
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      int row; // the row position
      int column; // the column position
      int space; // number of spaces to print

      // first triangle
      /* Write code to display the first triangle. Use nested for loops. The 
         outer loop should control which row of asterisks is being displayed.
         The inner loop should display one asterisk at a time. */
        for(row=1;row<11;row++)
        {
            for(column=0; column < row; column++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

      // second triangle
      /* Write code to display the second triangle. */
        System.out.print("\n");

        for(row=10;row>0;row--)
        {
            for(column=0; column < row; column++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");

        }


      // third triangle
      /* Write code to display the third triangle. The outer for loop should
         contain two separate inner for loops--one to display spaces and one to
         display asterisks. */
         System.out.print("\n");

        for(row=10; row > 0; row--)
        {
            for(column=0; column < row; column++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");


        }

      // fourth triangle
      /* Write code to display the fourth triangle using techniques similar to
         the third triangle. */

        for(row=1;row<11;row++)
        {
            for(column=0; column < row; column++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }


   } // end main
} // end class Triangles
```

Once that code is outputted it prints:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********

**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*

**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*

*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

instead of this I need this to print:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********

**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*

**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *

         *
        **
       ***
      ****
     *****
    ******
   *******
  ********
 *********
**********
```

I just want to know how to print spaces to place in the rows that I need to place them. Do I need to use an if statement or another for statement? Thank you for helping me in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret command to print spaces is:

```
System.out.print(" ");
```

So basically for the third triangle, print 'row' spaces then '10-row' asterix for row from 0 to 9 included.

For your fourth triangle you want print 10-'row' spaces then 'row' asterix for row from 1 to 10 included.

### EDIT

This should work.

```
// third triangle
for(row=0; row < 10; row++)
        {
            for(column=0; column < row; column++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(column=0; column < 10-row; column++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

For the fourth triangle, just change the first line to

```
    for(row=10; row > 0; row--)
```

Comment: how would that look in code because I understand the concept and how to simply print spaces, but I have tried a thousand different things but nothing seems to be working

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't know you could write '10-row' I'll keep that in mind next time